# image slider inside fragmnet activity not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

i'am following this tutorial 
http://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/ 
to make an image slider but it only works with activity how can i do it the same way in Fragment

Comment: post the code and error log if you already tried it

Comment: there is no error log just the view pager not working iam having trouble posting code here

Comment: the code is just like the tutrial only i call it from Fragment

Comment: Can you show your current code and explain what you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line in Fragment from

```
mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this,ImagesArray));
```

to

```
mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(getActivity(),ImagesArray));
```

Comment: i just did that  but it's not working

Comment: It must have error log somewhere. I can't help if i dont have it

Comment: thanks i just slve it it was layout problem